# What is causing all of the msrepl_tran_version columns to become out-of-sync between locations in transactional replication setup?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, replication

I have been having a recurring issue with transactional replication setups at the firm I work for. We use SQL 2008 R2. Seemingly without warning or any replication errors, all of the msrepl_tran_version columns (or nearly all of them) get out-of-sync between the two locations in a given setup.

I look in replication monitor and don't see any errors, and it's not as though the data changed for all the rows. Instead, most of the data remains identical between the two instances, but as users make changes at one location they don't update at the other due to the msrepl_tran_version columns being out-of-sync.

This issue is extremely frustrating, because I can't tell what's causing it and it requires substantial resynchronization to fix. Does anyone know what causes this symptom? Otherwise, does anyone have any ideas on how I can look to diagnose the issue? I would appreciate any advice anyone can provide.

Thanks.